# Can I use WHERE in CASE WHEN THEN?

Tags: mysql, sql

When I am using WHERE after THEN in CASE statement, It gives error like syntax error, so how I can to add condition in CASE THEN 
Example:

```
SELECT CASE when sum(price)>5000 THEN price WHERE name LIKE %%
```

OR

```
SELECT case when sum(price)>5000 THEN price = SELECT price from products where name LIke %%
```

But it gives out SYNTAX ERROR

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: Your code does not make sense.  You should explain what you want to do and provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WHERE is not allowed here.

Try this:

```
SELECT 
      CASE when sum(price) > 5000 
         THEN price 
         ELSE 'somethingElse' END 
   FROM 
      tableName 
   WHERE 
      name LIKE %%
```

or

```
SELECT 
      CASE when sum(price) > 5000 AND name LIKE %% 
           THEN price ELSE ... END
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer isn't intended as a solution for this XY problem.
Just see it as a MySql syntax experiment.

It is allowed to use a sub-query inside a CASE statement.
But that subquery must return only 1 result value or nothing.

For example this test snippet:

```
drop table if exists test;
create table test (name varchar(30), price int);
insert into test (name, price) values
  ('prod1', 1001)
, ('prod1', 1001)
, ('prod2', 2001), ('prod2', 2001), ('prod2', 2001)
, ('prod9999', 9999)
;

SELECT
 name,
 sum(price) as price,
 (CASE 
 WHEN sum(price)>5000 
 THEN (select sum(price) from test where name like '%prod999%')
 ELSE sum(price)
 END) as price2
from test
group by name;
```

Returns:

```
name     price  price2
prod1    2002  2002
prod2    6003  9999
prod9999 9999  9999
```

However, such method shouldn't be used.
That sub-query would be run multiple times.
And for no good reason, since the returned value would be the same each time.

In such situation the sub-query could be joined.

```
SELECT
 p.name,
 sum(p.price) as price,
 (CASE 
 WHEN sum(p.price)>5000
 THEN sum(prod999.price)
 ELSE sum(p.price)
 END) as price2
from test p
cross join (select sum(price) as price from test where name like '%prod999%') as prod999
group by p.name
order by p.name;
```